# Producing unique GIDs

Tags: php, math

I'm working on a way to produce unique GIDs and would like any opinion on the following code. The idea is that it should produce an ID that is unique to a specific IP within a time frame of 1 second (helps prevent multiple postings), and be as short as possible.

Here is the code in PHP:

```
$gid = base_convert(dechex(str_replace(".", "", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) . dechex(time()), 10, 36);
```

This produces IDs such as these:

```
qdkgzfvim
4ge6gesv
cztme7e4t
45qqcvq
```

Any opinion as to whether this would produce unique IDs? Can there be collisions? Should I pad the numbers with 0s?

Comment: Do you realise many PCs can share the same IP address?

Comment: Per-IP filtering is common for web services. REMOTE_ADDR can be replaced with userid in the case of a logged in user. Or, if it's used to generate user IDs, then it will prevent 2 persons from the same IP from registering at the exact same second...

Comment: I'm thinking more for a commenting system, or to generate IDs for users and other such things, where you don't expect someone from generating two items within a single second. The time() is an easy way to make it unique forever since it will keep incrementing. My question is more changing from int to hex and then to base36, does it lose uniqueness...

Comment: @Dendory - My company only uses a handful of IP addresses for external traffic. Modern routers can do this. IP/port mapping. Read up on the Cisco web site.

Comment: so, if 2 computers under same internet or same proxy will get you duplicate GIDs. try sth like MAC address

Comment: Why won't you use the [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function for that purpose?

Comment: That's not the question, it doesn't matter if this means 2 people on the same IP can't create IDs at the exact same second. The question is about uniqueness. Will this process of creating GIDs make unique IDs? Or does the process of concatenating the two values then converting to base36 produce collisions? And uniqid() isn't unique enough, 2 items made at the same time by different users will collide.

Comment: @Dendory - You want an opinion that using IP addresses for GUI is a good idea. And then throw in one second. Not it is not a good idea. Perhaps GUIDs would be better. Also why prevent a big company having clashes because lots of users share an IP address and invariable they may wish to access your site in one second

Comment: Why don't you just use a session variable timestamp? ie `$_SESSION['lastPost'] = time();` you can then compare this to the current time - an offset and either reject or allow the next post.

Comment: Again this has nothing to do with IPs or session IDs. The question is about the base conversion, and whether it will create collisions. We all know the numbers 1 to 99999999 are all unique, right? Well will base_convert(1, 10, 36) to base_convert(99999999, 10, 36) also stay unique or not?

Comment: There are some UUID libraries out there already which guarantee that thousands of servers generating millions of UUIDs continuously for millions of years will barely find on collision.

Comment: @Dendorym - You wrote " it should produce an ID that is unique to a specific IP within a time frame of 1 second" - You want it unique per IP address in a particular second

Comment: A 'standard' GUID is 16 bytes, certain to be unique, can be used as a 'reference' to identify any particular post. How long is the 'average post' and what percentage of space would be occupied by the 'GUID' over all the 'posts'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a test:

```
$part2 = dechex(time());

echo '<br/>' . $part2;

echo '<br/>' . base_convert($part2, 10, 36);

echo '<br/>' . base_convert(base_convert($part2, 10, 36), 36, 10);
```

Produces something like:

```
5435a0e0
bnd8
543500
```

Its losing data. So its not reversible, so therefore it could lose the supposed uniqueness.

Comment: That's the kind of answer I'm looking for. Shouldn't a base conversion *not* lose data, tho? I'm guessing this is due to how base_convert() works internally, since it's obviously not taking each digits individually? Any way to create a function that would convert into alphanumeric (with the goal of reducing string length) but not lose data?

Comment: @Dendory - Why worry about reducing it by 10 bytes? This is micro-optimisation and people tend to lose the bigger picture. BTW. Time is predictable so is this algorithm.

Comment: Solved it, thanks for pointing out this test. The issue is that those **10** should be **16**. Then it's unique, and will remain unique regardless of the time or IP.